# Como pegar outra div, com o mesmo nome sem alterar as outras?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Bem é o seguinte. Tenho a seguinte estrutura de código:

Um div chamada part-sec que traz todo o conteúdo do produto. A div preco-produto vem com o preço. Até aí tudo bem. Mas embaixo eu tenho outra div com os tamanhos e quando a pessoa clica no tamanho ele tem que mudar a div preco-produto com o preço do tamanho que a pessoa clicou. Mas o problema é que tem várias divs iguais a esta e se eu clicar ele muda o preço do tamanho clicado em todas as divs. Eu queria que ele mudasse o preço somente do produto com a div clicada. Já tentei com this e não deu certo!

pequeno
médio
grande

Comment: Olá Felipe, você poderia editar sua pergunta acrescentando um pouco de código para que fique mais claro o problema?

Comment: Para entender melhor, leia o guia que explica o que é um [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fala Felipe,

você está dando a ordem para mudar todas as divs com a classe "precoproduto". Para resolver seu problema, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
$(document).on("click",".tam-selecionado",function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    //separamos o elemento do click
    var elemento = $(this);
    .
    .
    .
    .

    elemento.closest('.part-info').find('.precoproduto').html(precoproduto);
```

basicamente separamos o elemento do clique; através dele procuramos a div pai mais próxima com a classe 'part-info'; vamos até a classe 'precoproduto' e alteramos o valor

Comment: Ok muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito;

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca caso esteja tudo certo, marque a resposta como correta para ajudarmos mais pessoas.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Código html da página]
[image: Imagem dos produtos com o preço igual em todos, quando clicado no tamanho]

Quando passar o mouse no tipo de Item (pequeno, médio, grande), seleciona o grande; e ele muda no X-SALADA e no X-TUDO o preço, ou seja o preço fica igual. No entanto ele deveria somente mudar o preço no X-SALADA, não no X-TUDO. Segue o código:

$(document).on("click",".tam-selecionado",function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();

```
    var tamanhoSelecionado = $(this).text();
    var idcategoria = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var idproduto =  $(this).attr("data-produto-id");
    var precoproduto = "";

    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://teste/store/produtos?filter[categoria_id]=' + idcategoria,
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(retorno)
      {

        retorno.data.forEach(function(item)
        {
          var idprodutoselecionado = item.produto_id;

          if (idprodutoselecionado == idproduto)
          {

            item.tamanho.forEach(function(tamanho)
            {

              tamanhoProdutoArray = tamanho.tamanho.nome;

              if (tamanhoProdutoArray == tamanhoSelecionado)
              {
                precoproduto = tamanho.valor;
                **$(".precoproduto class-id" + idproduto  + "").empty();
                $(".precoproduto").html(precoproduto);**
              }

            })
          }

        })
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
        alert("Status do Servidor: " + textStatus);
        alert("Erro do Servidor: " + errorThrown);
      }

    });
  });
});
```